# internet connection requires login ....minimal install

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-minimal

my wired internet connection requires login before using internet means when you try to open google.com ,it wil redirect you to login page ....hence i cant download components using minimal install .....please help me,how to enter login details during minimal installation [[[step by step]]] ...i think while installing the proxy part has something to do with these

and how much megabytes of needs to be downloaded ..................
my internet speed is six megabytes per minutes ......so how much time it will take for installation

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a cheap router to the wired internet connection, and then use a computer that has a browser to log onto the internet. This way, the 'login page' or whoever is providing the internet will match your routers mac address, allowing you to connect anything to the router without having to 'log on' to use the internet.